# Partial derivates of function containing a definite integral.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

So i have the function $f(x,y) = \int_{0}^{x^2+y}t+e^{-t^2} dt$ which im supposed to find the partial derivates of.

Now after looking online i was able to solve this by using the leibniz rule. (Could be very wrong though)

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} = 2x-4xe^{-(x^2+y)^2}(x^2+y)$$

$$\frac{ \partial }{ \partial y } = 1-2e^{-(x^2+y)^2}(x^2+y)$$

Now the thing is, we havent covered the leibniz rule so im wondering if there are any other "easier" ways you can solve this or reason your way forward.

Comment: The Leibniz rule deals specifically with the situation when the function you're integrating depends on an auxiliary variable, like $F(x)=\int_0^{f(x)} g(x,t)\,dt$. In your case, $x,y$ appear only in the limit of the integral, so you need only the Fundamental Theorem (and chain rule).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the Leibniz rule. The answers that you got follow from the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: The Leibniz rule is for differentiating things of the type $x\mapsto\int_a^bf(x,y)\,\mathrm dy$. On the other hand, the fundamental theorem of Calculus is for differentiating things of the type $x\mapsto\int_a^xf(y)\,\mathrm dy$. That's what you are using here, right?!

Comment: Yeah, i might have misread some things. My bad

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I will, im just not sure if i have the right answer yet.  How  exactly would you use the fundemental theorem + chain rule in this case?. Im just kinda throw off by the whole multivariable thing.

Comment: In order to differentiate, in order to $x$, your function, you see it as the composition of $x\mapsto x^2+y$ with the function $x\mapsto\int_0^xt+e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt$. So, by the chain rule, you get$$2x\times\left(x^2+y+e^{-(x^2+y)^2}\right).$$

Comment: Oh, yeah now i get it. Cheers!